# How to use sed with a file of patterns and sed in place

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to use  a list of patterns to search in 4 large files, and remove the line that contains the regex.

I tried to specify the file path but it didn't work

> sed -n '/{home/dirco/shut}/p' rimco rimco2 aval aval2

I tried to use sed option `-f` but it didn't work either

> sed -f home/dirco/shut rimco rimco2 aval aval2

ultimately the goal will be to sed in place by removing that line if the pattern is found.

Comment: The syntax in your first `sed` command is almost certainly wrong, but without an explanation of what it's supposed to do, we can't tell you how to correct it.

Comment: I do not think that would make any difference at all, the problem here is not the the pattern ,but the location of the pattern, instead of having that the command. I'm trying to read all the patterns from a file. using a loop will take forever due the size of the files.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's#/#\\/#g;s#.*#/&/p#g' patternFile | sed -nf - file1 file2 file3 ...
```

Turn the patternFile into a sed script and run it against the data files.

N.B. The sed delimiter `/` is first quoted and the each line of the patternFile is turned into an address which is printed `/pattern/p`.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, I keep getting  `command not found`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, I keep getting `command not found` at the end of each line

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cmd=$(
echo -n "sed -i '"
while read -r line; do
    echo -n "/$line/d;"
done < patternfile.txt
echo "'"
)
"$cmd" rimco rimco2 aval aval2
```

Comment: thanks for you reply but due to the size of the files this will take days, to sed trough each lines. in the description I mentioned 4 large files (around 10Gb each)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do what you want efficiently and robustly by using GNU awk for inplace editing (assuming your list of regexps in `regexpsfile` isn't massive):

```
awk -i inplace 'NR==FNR{re=re sep "(" $0 ")"; sep="|"} NR!=FNR && $0~re{next} 1' regexpsfile rimco rimco2 aval aval2
```